# SQL Query to match preferences

Tags: mysql, sql, psql

I'm trying to match a clients preferences to a house/flat. I've tried the following query below, however it seems to reject it, any ideas why?

```
select b.*
from propertyforrent b, client a
where a.fname = 'John'
having a.preftype = b.type and a.maxrent <= b.rent;
```

Comment: which of three tags is correct?? i mean which environment are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
select b.*
  from propertyforrent b
  join client a
    on a.preftype = b.type
 where a.fname = 'John'
   and a.maxrent <= b.rent
```

The HAVING clause is for comparing aggregate values.

"a.preftype = b.type" is a join condition (use join clause)

"a.maxrent <= b.rent" is a horizontal comparison (not an aggregate/vertical comparison)

Comment: Thanks man! The a.maxrent <= b.rent is the wrong way around but apart from that I get exactly what I wanted. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `having` when you're also using `group by` (with an aggregate query).  Perhaps you're looking for something more like this:

```
select b.*
from propertyforrent b
   join client a on a.preftype = b.type and a.maxrent <= b.rent
where a.fname = 'John'
```

Answer (score 0):

`having` is used after `group by`, see [MySQL - SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

What you have here is an implicit join between two tables `propertyforrent` and `client`. You can either say

```
select b.*
from propertyforrent b, client a
where a.fname = 'John' and a.preftype = b.type and a.maxrent <= b.rent;
```

or use an explicit `join`

```
select b.*
from propertyforrent b
join client a on a.preftype = b.type
where a.fname = 'John' and and a.maxrent <= b.rent;
```